# Passing arguments of a function as parameter names in other function

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Lets assume we have two functions `foo` and `get_id`in Python3. I want to call the `get_id` function inside the `foo` function while using an argument of the `foo` function as an argument name in the `get_id` function. For example:

I call the `foo` function:

`result = foo("Person","name","John")`

while the body of the function is:

`def foo(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):
    res = get_id(arg_1, arg_2 = arg_3)
    return res`

What i want is:

`res = get_id("Person", name = "John")`

so that the get_id function will be parameterized by the arg_2 argument of the foo function. However, the way i am doing it so far results in error as python interpretes it as a String.Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You could just do it inside the function. Like `get_id(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):    arg_2 = arg_3`

Comment: No that doesn't work.

Comment: What is the specific use case for this?

Comment: The get_id function belongs to an imported package and i need to use it in this specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should probably *not* try to understand why you want to do this :) but here is a solution maybe:

```
def foo(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3):
    kwargs = {
        'arg_1_name': arg_1,
        arg_2: arg_3,
    }
    return get_id(**kwargs)
```

just make sure to replace `arg_1_name` with the actual name of the parameter used in the `get_id` function

Comment: "I should probably not try to understand why you want to do this" => indeed :-|

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to pass parameter name as string :

```
def test(a):
    print(a)

test(**{'a': 'hello world'})
```

I'm sure you can adapt this solution to your problem